# Dynamicly generated file download in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

Yet another question on how to download a file generated via Web API.

Having a .NET web app, with Web API controllers using token based authentication and plain MVC views with knockout/jquery.

My question is:
What's the best way to return a file download as a response in client browser?

Looking at the following approach:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/api/Returns",
        data: { fromMonth: selFromMonth.value, toMonth: selToMonth.value},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken },
        success: function (result) {              
            ...
        }
      });
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't make an ajax call. Make a normal http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've end up adding the following code in the success callback`
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                var txt = document.createElement("input");

```
            form.method = "POST";
            form.action = "/api/Reports";

            txt.value = JSON.stringify(result);
            txt.name = "txt";
            txt.type = "hidden";

            form.appendChild(txt);

            document.body.appendChild(form);

            form.submit(); `
```

Also had to add the following changes on the Web API method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
{
     if (jsonbody["data"] != null)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Return>>(jsonbody["data"].ToString());

        }
}
```

A bit more explanation on what's the idea behind all this:

1. Send an AJAX request to a Web API method in order to obtain required data. Bearer token passed in order to authenticate the request.
2. Json result from request in 1. is stored in a hidden input field.
3. A new form object is dynamically created containing the hidden input field.
4. Form submits a "POST" request to an other Web API method (no authorization required) which generates the required output file and returns that to the browser.

Hope that would be useful to someone.